# How to get the inserted document in response of the insert method with MongoDB driver 4.2?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In MongoDB 3.6 the insert method returned the inserted document. However, in the latest MongoDB 4.2 driver only the inserted Id is returned, is there a way to get the inserted document as well instead of doing of findOne query?

Answer (score 0):

try to use  **returnDocument: 'after'** in your options opbject

Comment: No use, adding the above option did not return the inserted document.